# Interference of light and sound waves

Tags: waves, interference

In Young's double slit experiment a single monochromatic light source was split into two monochromatic light sources which was in same phase to produce interference.

So my question is, instead of taking transverse wave, can a longitudinal wave (say, sound wave) will also produce interference using double slit experiment?

If so, then how?

Comment: have a look at this experiment with sound waves https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk_I59OWvd8

Comment: Not only is this an easy experiment to do at home, but if you have old fashioned speakers where you plug the wires into the back yourself you can reverse the polarity of one and turn noes into anti-nodes and vice versa.

Comment: @dmckee I think the OPs question was about transverse vs longitudinal interference in the double slit experiment.

Comment: @user45664 Yes? I mean, what better way to *know* that you can do it with longitudinal waves than actually doing it? And there is an added bonus in that you can easily perform a variation that is hard to do with light.